# pandas: group by custom categories, then pivot?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
              Company Name                          Category  Amount
0             Teva Limited  Consultancy                     650.000
1             Teva Limited  Consultancy                       5.300
2        Eli & Company Ltd  Events                           15.000
3                     Meda  Events                           60.000
4             Teva Limited  Events                          400.000
4             Teva Limited  Travel                          202.000
4                     Meda  Travel                          399.860
```

I want to create a new dataframe with a row for each company, and two columns: the total spent on consultancy, and the total spent on everything else, meaning events + travel.

So it should look something like this:

```
 Company Name        Spend Consultancy     Spend Other
 Teva UK Limited     653.000               602.000
 Meda Pharma         0.000                 459.860
```

What is the best way to do this?

I have grouped it by name and category and summed the amount, which is a start:

```
df.groupby(('Company Name', 'Category')).sum()
```

But now I'm not sure how to combine the categories together in a bespoke way, or how to pivot them into columns. I think I might need a pivot table?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [assign()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for creating a new `cat` column containing only `['Consultancy', 'Other']` categories and then use this new column in  `pivot_table()` function :

```
In [10]: (df.assign(cat=np.where(df.Category=='Consultancy', df.Category, 'Other'))
   ....:    .pivot_table(index='Company Name', columns='cat', values='Amount',
   ....:                 aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
   ....: )
Out[10]:
cat                Consultancy   Other
Company Name
Eli & Company Ltd          0.0   15.00
Meda                       0.0  459.86
Teva Limited             655.3  602.00
```

or having `Company Name`as a regular column:

```
In [17]: %paste
(df.assign(cat=np.where(df.Category=='Consultancy', df.Category, 'Other'))
   .pivot_table(index='Company Name', columns='cat', values='Amount',
                aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
   .reset_index()
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[17]:
cat       Company Name  Consultancy   Other
0    Eli & Company Ltd          0.0   15.00
1                 Meda          0.0  459.86
2         Teva Limited        655.3  602.00
```

Explanation:

```
In [11]: df.assign(cat=np.where(df.Category=='Consultancy', df.Category, 'Other'))
Out[11]:
        Company Name     Category  Amount          cat
0       Teva Limited  Consultancy  650.00  Consultancy
1       Teva Limited  Consultancy    5.30  Consultancy
2  Eli & Company Ltd       Events   15.00        Other
3               Meda       Events   60.00        Other
4       Teva Limited       Events  400.00        Other
5       Teva Limited       Travel  202.00        Other
6               Meda       Travel  399.86        Other
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
cdf = df.groupby([df['Company Name'], df.Category == 'Consultancy']).Amount.sum().unstack().fillna(0)
cdf.set_axis(1, ['Other', 'Consultancy'])
print cdf

                    Other  Consultancy
Company Name                          
Eli & Company Ltd   15.00          0.0
Meda               459.86          0.0
Teva Limited       602.00        655.3
```